# Spring Data Redis 3.2.2 support for Jedis 5.0.2 MultiClusterClientConfig

Tags: redis, spring-data-redis, jedis, failover

Jedis 5.0.2 has support for multi-cluster failover with MultiClusterClientConfig. I am using spring data redis (3.2.2) abstraction for Redis integration, I am not able to find option to configure MultiClusterClientConfig in RedisClusterConfiguration. Does spring-data-redis supports Jedis' failover feature?

Comment: No. spring-data-redis doesn't support multi-cluster.